# Symfony2 extends twig in bundle - no effect

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I do my first project in Symfony2. I have problem with template. My main twig file is "`index.html.twig`". It's located in `src/Gogs/CMSBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig`

I try to extends main twig file from `content.html.twig` -> it's also in the same directory.

In `index.html.twig` I have `{% block body %}{% endblock %}`.

My `content.html.twig` looks like:

```
{% extends 'GogsCMSBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
Some content
{% endblock %}
```

I was looking solution on many forums, but nothing working. Symfony doesn't give me any errors - no effect.

When I try to use include in `index.html.twig` , it's work perfectly. Code below.

```
{% include "GogsCMSBundle:Default:content.html.twig" %}
```

I tried to use also another commands:

```
 {% extends 'GogsCMSBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}
 {% extends 'GogsCMSBundle::index.html.twig' %}
 {% extends 'GogsCMSBundle:index.html.twig' %}
 {% extends '::index.html.twig' %}
 {% extends 'index.html.twig' %}
```

All of them doesn't give any effect - no errors too.

My main controller:

```
 return $this->render('GogsCMSBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $page, 'menu' => $menu));
```

I cleaned Cache many times.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Any exceptions or error messages?

Comment: Content from 'content.html.twig' doesn't show in index.html.twig - there is no errors or messages. Nothing. I dont know why

Comment: You know you set your controller to render `index.html.twig` and not `content.html.twig` which extends your `index` file right? Or is it a typo because of copying code?

Comment: `class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
$page = $menu = "page_name";
        return $this->render('GogsCMSBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $page, 'menu' => $menu));
    }` 
hmm . I render index.html.twig - not content

Comment: Which is why your text defined in `content.html.twig` does not show. You have to set this template to be rendered in your controller, because it's the one that extends your `index.html.twig` file which is used like a layout.

Comment: Omg , Artamiel you're the best :D I'm so stupid. I use render content.html.twig and everything is working :) Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Artamiel found the answer...

Bug is in Controller. Contoller must indicate a `content.html.twig`.

So solution:

**index.html.twig**

```
{# src/Gogs/CMSBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig #}

{% block body %}{% endblock %}.
```

**content.html.twig**

```
{# src/Gogs/CMSBundle/Resources/views/Default/content.html.twig #}
    {% extends 'GogsCMSBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
    Some content
    {% endblock %}
```

**Contoller.php**

```
return $this->render('GogsCMSBundle:Default:content.html.twig');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need move indexd.html.twig in app\Resources\views = this is a base layout of the symfony. Next create in src/YourBundle/Resources/views layout.html.twig -which extend index.html.twig:

```
 {% extends '::index.html.twig' %}
```

And finally, add in content.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'GogsCMSBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

More information  [there](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations)

Comment: That's no true. I no need move index to app. Now everything works perfect and everything is only in bundle.